# How to find out how many issues were opened/closed in a certain timespan via GitLab API?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I want to find out how many issues were opened in a specific GitLab group in the last year, regardless if they are still open or are closed now.

And I want to find out how many issues were closed in a specific GitLab group in the last year, regardless when they were opened.

Is this possible?

I found the [GitLab Issues statistics API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues_statistics.html#get-group-issues-statistics) and tried these queries but I cannot interpret the results:

I used created_before/created_after:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <token>" "https://<gitlab-url>/api/v4/groups/<group-id>/issues_statistics?created_after=2023-01-01T00:00:00Z&created_before=2024-01-01T00:00:00Z"

{"statistics":{"counts":{"all":226,"closed":149,"opened":77}}}
```

and updated_before/updated_after:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <token>" "https://<gitlab-url>/api/v4/groups/<group-id>/issues_statistics?updated=2023-01-01T00:00:00Z&updated_before=2024-01-01T00:00:00Z"

{"statistics":{"counts":{"all":536,"closed":433,"opened":103}}}
```

My best guess is, it's just a typo, and it means "closed" and "open" not "opened"?

Or is there a completely different way to find out what I am looking for?